# Pattern matching on a keyword list

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to take certain fields out of a keyword list. I've tried this but I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong?

```
[what: "country", url: "asdf", matches: "AQ"]
|> Enum.map(fn([:what, :url, :matches]) -> [:what, :url] end)
```

Edit:

Intended output is:

```
[what: "country", url: "asdf"]
```

Comment: For anyone curious about pattern matching keyword lists: ["Although we can pattern match on keyword lists, it is rarely done in practice since pattern matching on lists requires the number of items and their order to match"](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `Enum.map` on a keyword list, you go through the tuples `{key, value}`, one by one. Which causes the error `** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching`.

It depends on what you want as a result. If you want a subset of the keyword list, as a keyword list, you can do

```
[what: "country", url: "asdf", matches: "AQ"]
|> Keyword.take([:what, :url])
```

Which will return `[what: "country", url: "asdf"]`

If you want a Map as a result instead, you can use the solution proposed above by @denis.peplin

If for some reason you still want or need to do it using `Enum.map` and pattern matching, you can do something like:

```
[what: "country", url: "asdf"]
|> Enum.map(fn
  {k, _v} = tup when k in [:what, :url] -> tup
  _ -> nil
end) |> Enum.reject(&is_nil/1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[what: "country", url: "asdf", matches: "AQ"]
|> Map.new()
|> Map.take([:what, :url])
```

I'm not sure it's the most idiomatic way. Do you want a keyword list as an output instead?

Edit:

The answer was posted before the edit was made to the question, so it's not very relevant now.

If a keyword list is needed as an output, use `Keyword.take` instead.

Comment: You can directly use `Keyword.take/2` on the keyword list. `[what: "country", url: "asdf", matches: "AQ"] |> Keyword.take([:what, :url])`, which returns a keyword list

Comment: @sbacaro, post this as an answer. Let's see what cjm2671 actually wants.